# How to add text to a .txt file in NodeJS in a new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, node-modules

So I have a basic script which generates a bitcoin address and its private key using a module.

Using the fs module, I have created two text files: address.txt and keys.txt and I append the addresses onto the address.txt and the keys onto the keys.txt

The problem is that I want each key and address in a new line, but when I append them they are in a single line and its pretty much useless to me

here's the code('pub' and 'priv' and the address and key variables)

```
fs.appendFile('addresses.txt', pub)
fs.appendFile('keys.txt', priv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appendFile method will only append the data to the file, it will not create add new lines to the file. If your content have the new line then same will reflect in the file.

if you want to add pub, priv (address & key) variables to new line in their respective files then you just append "\n" to these variable every time. So, that each and every address and keys will be append new lines only.